# Select records from database WHERE but at least

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Suppose I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Message` (
  `ConMsgID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SenderID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReceiverID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Text` text NOT NULL,
  `DateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ReadStatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ReadDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ConMsgID`),
  KEY `UserID` (`SenderID`),
  KEY `ReceiverID` (`ReceiverID`)
)
```

This is a chat messages table. Just imagine 2 users are chatting with each other. USER1 and USER2

CASE 1:

USER1 send USER2, 20 messages and and are unread by USER2. When USER2 open conversation he must see all 20 messages.

CASE 2:

USER2 reply USER1 and send 3 messages and are unread by USER1. When USER1 open conversation he will see last 15 messages total of both users.

Hope I am clear now

Answer (score 1):

Sort your data accordingly and limit the result to 15 records

```
SELECT * 
FROM msgs 
ORDER BY case when ReadStatus = 0 then 1 else 2 end asc,
         id desc
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: but what if I have messages with ReadStatus=0 are less than 15?

Comment: This does what you are asking.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. let me edit my question and try to be more clear.